# Failed to load assembly, 0 bytes from System, BadImageFormatException

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

We've install .Net 4.0 Full at a client site.  Current System.dll version is 4.0.30319.236.

Our test application opens without a problem and I initiate a simple "echo" to a WCF service on the same network.  However, I get this nasty error when the service call is invoked:

```
Creating proxy
calling service method
ERROR: exception during service call and response process: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
System.BadImageFormatException
```

Stack trace:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoadImage(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence evidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean fIntrospection, SecurityContextSource securityContextSource)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Byte[] rawAssembly, Byte[] rawSymbolStore, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GenerateSerializers()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.SerializerGenerationContext.GetSerializer(Int32 handle)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.MessageInfo.get_BodySerializer()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object returnValue, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion version, Object[] parameters, Object returnValue, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriter.WriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at Microsoft.Samples.CompressionEncoder.MyCompressionMessageEncoderFactory.MyCompressionMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset) in C:\Projects\TariffServices\TariffService\Source\Service Interface\CompressionEncoder\MyCompressionMessageEncoderFactory.cs:line 163
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.EncodeMessage(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionDuplexChannelGeneric`1.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

We've re-installed the framework numerous times, I've tried re-ngen'ing the System.dll.  Nothing works.

I've run the .Net setup verification tools, comes back with no errors.

The System.dll has a size of 3 510 600 bytes.

On the server machine (hosting the WCF service), everything is fine.  The .Net version on that machine is also 4.0.30319.236.

Both machines are on WinXP 32bit Professional SP3, 2GB RAM.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Make sure that your code doesn't require anything dependent on x64 platform. Try to compile your application explicitly demanding x86 (32bit) to exclude this possibility.

Comment: But why would the call work on the server machine and not across the wire?  Surely, the same error must occur, too?

Answer (score 0):

We've shelved this problem for now. There seems to be more wrong with this PC than meets the eye. We've recommended a re-format and installation of WinXP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be connected to problem with csc.exe (used by code generator) not producing any output. Check this url for how to fix the issue: http://www.nooto.com/2011/02/net-framework-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/